# Write code to simulate Depth First Search (DFS) by reading from File using Java

Tags: java, depth-first-search

Write code to simulate Depth First Search (DFS) by reading `FinalQ1Input.txt` using Java File I/O, and the starting vertex is 0.

The output should look like the following:

[image]

`FinalQ1Input.txt` values are here:

[image]

And my code is:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 


     // Ref --> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-search-or-dfs-for-a-graph/

    // This class represents a directed graph using adjacency list 
    // representation 
    class SP2020_CSE373_Final_Q2_1234567 
    { 
        private int V;   // No. of vertices 

        // Array  of lists for Adjacency List Representation 
        private LinkedList<Integer> adj[]; 

        // Constructor 
        SP2020_CSE373_Final_Q2_1234567(int v) 
        { 
            V = v; 
            adj = new LinkedList[v]; 
            for (int i=0; i<v; ++i) 
                adj[i] = new LinkedList(); 
        } 

        //Function to add an edge into the graph 
        void addEdge(int v, int w) 
        { 
            adj[v].add(w);  // Add w to v's list. 
        } 

        // A function used by DFS 
        void DFSUtil(int v,boolean visited[]) 
        { 
            // Mark the current node as visited and print it 
            visited[v] = true; 
            System.out.print(v+" "); 

            // Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex 
            Iterator<Integer> i = adj[v].listIterator(); 
            while (i.hasNext()) 
            { 
                int n = i.next(); 
                if (!visited[n]) 
                    DFSUtil(n, visited); 
            } 
        } 

        // The function to do DFS traversal. It uses recursive DFSUtil() 
        void DFS(int v) 
        { 
            // Mark all the vertices as not visited(set as 
            // false by default in java) 
            boolean visited[] = new boolean[V]; 

            // Call the recursive helper function to print DFS traversal 
            DFSUtil(v, visited); 
        } 

        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
        { 
            System.out.print("15 32 \n");
            System.out.println("Vertices : \n { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, \n  10, 11, 12, 13, 14 }");
            System.out.println("Edges : \n { (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 6),\n"
                    + "(1, 3), (6, 3), (2, 3), (3, 7), (2, 7),\n"
                    + "(6, 4), (3, 4), (3, 5), (5, 7), (4, 5),\n"
                    + "(4, 9), (6, 9), (9, 10), (4, 10), (5, 10),\n"
                    + "(5, 11), (10, 11), (7, 11), (9, 10), (10, 11),\n"
                    + "(10, 12), (10, 13), (9, 14), (11, 14), (1, 14),\n"
                    + "(2, 14) }");
            System.out.print("Enter the source vertex: ");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int a = input.nextInt();

             BufferedReader inFile;
             inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/hp/eclipse-workspace/Final_Assignment/src/SP2020_CSE373_Final_Q2_1234567/FinalQ1Input.txt"));
             File file = new File("C:/Users/hp/eclipse-workspace/Final_Assignment/src/SP2020_CSE373_Final_Q2_1234567/FinalQ1Input.txt");
             Scanner fIn = new Scanner(file);
             fIn.nextLine(); //skipping the first line!
             while (fIn.hasNext())
             {
                // System.out.print(fIn.next());
                 System.out.print(" Visited Vertex:  ");
                 System.out.print(fIn.nextInt());
                 System.out.print(" Parents:  ");
                 System.out.println(fIn.nextBigInteger());
             }
             fIn.close();






            // SP2020_CSE373_Final_Q2_1234567 g = new SP2020_CSE373_Final_Q2_1234567(4); 

          /*  g.addEdge(0, 1); 
            g.addEdge(0, 2); 
            g.addEdge(1, 2); 
            g.addEdge(2, 0); 
            g.addEdge(2, 3); 
            g.addEdge(3, 3); */

         //   System.out.println("Following is Depth First Traversal "+ 
                           //    "(starting from vertex 2)"); 
          //  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
           // g.DFS(2); 
        } 
    }
```

What's wrong with my code? My output is showing a garbage value.

Comment: Please post the desired output an data as formatted text, not as images. Do you think that anybody is ready to manually copy the input data from an image?

Comment: Decompose the problem into smaller ones. First get the input and construct a correct graph. I do not see it in the code.

Comment: I can't solve this problem..can you help me to fix my code?  @c0der

Comment: You have to use the numbers you read from the file to build a graph `SP2020_CSE373_Final_Q2_1712145 g = new SP2020_CSE373_Final_Q2_1712145(15)`  and then add 31 edges in a loop.

Comment: how can i add 31 edges in a loop ? @c0der

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<15;i++){ /*read 15 pairs of numbers from file and g.addEdge(n1,n2)*/  };`

Comment: the output is showing like this :

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextBigInteger(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextBigInteger(Unknown Source)
 at SP2020_CSE373_Final_Q2_1234567.SP2020_CSE373_Final_Q2_1712145.main(SP2020_CSE373_Final_Q2_1712145.java:86)